# How do I create an .exe which cycles through 3 Python scripts in order

Tags: python, exe

I have three scripts

1. Create_Image.py
2. Add_PNG.py
3. Combine.py

And I'd like to create an .exe or .bat file which runs the three of them one after another.

I paid a developer to do this, but he created an .exe which is static and doesn't respond to changes in the .py scripts.

Answer (score 2):

`.bat` file is just a script for Windows. So you probably could make a script like this:

```
python [your_1_python_script_name]
python [your_2_python_script_name]
python [your_3_python_script_name]
```

However, your script would have to be in the same directory as python files

Comment: Worth to mention, that developer probably did something different. They packaged the python code into `.exe` file with `pyinstaller` or similar package.
That solution has some benefits, mainly it doesn't require python to be installed on machine in which it runs.